# How to solve a system of linear equations with b=0 in R (with free variable)

Tags: r, math, linear-algebra

i.e. how to find the non-trivial solution.

Example :

```
> A = structure(c(1, -0.6, -0.4, -0.4, 0.9, -0.5, -0.6, -0.2, 0.8), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))
> A
     [,x1] [,x2] [,x3]
[1,]  1.0 -0.4 -0.6
[2,] -0.6  0.9 -0.2
[3,] -0.4 -0.5  0.8
> b0
     [,1]
[1,]    0
[2,]    0
[3,]    0
> solve(A,b0)
 [,1]
[1,]    0
[2,]    0
[3,]    0
```

The answer should be :

x = x3 * (0.94,0.85,1)

Or if you can recommend me other Open source tool that can solve such systems.

---

I'm taking this example from Linear algebra book.. the matrix reduce to :

```
1 0 -0.94 0
0 1 -0.85 0
0 0  0    0
```

i.e. x3 is free variable.
So parametrized solution is :

```
x = (x1,x2,x3) = (0.94 x3,0.85 x3, x3 ) = x3 * (0.94,0.85,1)
```

Sorry I did not emphasize earlier, I know that zero-vector is the trivial solution, I'm looking for the non-trivial solution.
thanks.

---

You are correct I had a typo (corrected):

```
> B = structure(c(1, -0.6, -0.4, -0.4, 0.9, -0.5, -0.6, -0.2, 0.8), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))
> B %*% c(.94,.85,1)
          [,1]
[1,] -1.110223e-16
[2,]  1.000000e-03
[3,] -1.000000e-03
> B %*% c(94,85,100)
  [,1]
[1,]  0.0
[2,]  0.1
[3,] -0.1
> det(B)
[1] 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any 3x3 matrix `A`, it is the case that `A %*% c(0,0,0)` is `c(0,0,0)`.  So the return value of zero is correct.  It is a solution.

Are there any other solutions?  A matrix admitting a nontrivial solution to `A x = 0` is called "singular".  The solution to the equation is called the "Null space."

The null space is spanned by the eigenvectors associated with eigenvalue 0.  These are given by `eigen`:

```
> eigen(B)
$values
[1] 1.350000e+00+1.32288e-01i 1.350000e+00-1.32288e-01i 1.171856e-16+0.00000e+00i

$vectors
                 [,1]             [,2]         [,3]
[1,] -0.4724556-0.25i -0.4724556+0.25i 0.5823201+0i
[2,]  0.7559289+0.00i  0.7559289+0.00i 0.5259665+0i
[3,] -0.2834734+0.25i -0.2834734-0.25i 0.6198891+0i
```

Note that the eigenvalues are in decreasing order, and the last one is (nearly) zero.  So `eigen(B)$vectors[,3]` is the solution here:

```
> eigen(B)$vectors[,3]
[1] 0.5823201+0i 0.5259665+0i 0.6198891+0i
```

Any multiple of this value is in the null space of `B`.

Another way to find this is with `MASS::Null`:

```
> Null(t(B))
          [,1]
[1,] 0.5823201
[2,] 0.5259665
[3,] 0.6198891
```

The matrix is transposed because you want the "right" null space.  See `?Null`.

Note:

```
> x <- Null(t(B))
> x/x[3]
          [,1]
[1,] 0.9393939
[2,] 0.8484848
[3,] 1.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks alot... I don't know yet about Null spaces and such... they are further in Linear algebra... but now that you mentioned it will take a look...
Also I have idea of eigen-val/vec, but didnt knew I can use them this way..
I now see the pattern of solving it ... will have to read more and experiment.. thank you again for detailed answer.

Comment: @user1019129 That's to make it look like your solution above, with the third element of `1`.  `eigen` and `Null` return vectors of length 1, but any multiple is in the null space.

Comment: So in a sense I can make any variable  be "the-free variable" ... f.e. x/x[2] ... sort of rescaling the other vars against the current one.